# glreadpixels return wrong value on different screen

Tags: objective-c, opengl

So I have plugin that show differently on different machine. On my machine, when I pass in the image I generate with 32 * 32 * 32 value. with every 32 have red value go from 0 - 1. I get back correctly, every 32 pixel, the red value go from 0-1.
But same code, same program I run on my co-worker machine, it not every 32 pixels but 64 pixel the red value go from 0 - 1. 
Is this problem related to screen resolution? how I can get back correct value that I pass in.

Example (first 32 pixel with red value)
Pass in 
0, 8, 16 24, 32, 40, ... 248
Correct one (my machine)
0, 8, 16 24, .... 248
Wrong ( co-worker machine . 
0, 4, 8, 12, 16 ...   124

Here is my code to create the texture base on Bit map

```
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, _texID);

   if (_texID) {
       glDeleteTextures(1, &_texID);
       _texID = 0;
   }
   glGenTextures(1, &_texID);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGBA8, (int)_imageSize.width, (int)_imageSize.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _image_buffer);

   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Here code to generate the bit map

```
    [self setFrameSize:_imageSize];
    GLubyte al = 255;  // alpha value
    double increment = (al+1) / val;
    _totalByteSize = val*val*val*4;
    _image_buffer = new GLubyte[_totalByteSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < (_totalByteSize); i++) {
        _image_buffer[i] = 0;
    }
    vector<GLKVector3> data;

    GLubyte bl  = 0;
    GLubyte gr  = 0;
    GLubyte re  = 0;
    for ( int b = 0; b < val; b++) {
        gr = 0;
        for ( int g = 0; g < val; g++) {
            re = 0;
            for ( int r = 0; r < val; r++) {
                int ind = r + g * val + b * val * val;

                _image_buffer[ind * 4 + 0] = re;
                _image_buffer[ind * 4 + 1] = gr;
                _image_buffer[ind * 4 + 2] = bl;
                _image_buffer[ind * 4 + 3] = al;
                re+= increment;  // 256 / 32 = 8
            }
            gr+= increment; // 256 / 32 = 8
        }
        bl+= increment; // 256 / 32 = 8
    }
```

And here code to read

```
    int totalByteSize = 32*32*32*3;
    GLubyte* bitmap = new GLubyte[totalByteSize];

    glReadPixels(0, 0, _imageSize.width, _imageSize.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap);
    [_lutData removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= totalByteSize /3 ; i++) {
        double val1 = (double)bitmap[i*3+0] / 256.0;
        double val2 = (double)bitmap[i*3+1] / 256.0;
        double val3 = (double)bitmap[i*3+2] / 256.0;

        [_lutData addObject:@[@(val1), @(val2), @(val3)]];
    }
```

Does this can cause by screen with high resolution or different setting causing it to read wrong

Comment: Are you using the same values for glViewport?

Comment: yes. It is the same code without change anything. The only different between is different computer.glViewport(0, 0, size.width,size.height);

Comment: Are size.width and size.height the same values on both computers?

Comment: YES. So i got the reason why. It is the retina display screen.  But I am still experiment how to get the whole image. Right now it still missing half of the image.